# in posrtgresql how to declare a column that has reference to a table but also can receive null and can be saved through Django model

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

In my data base I have a school table with id, name and phone number
and a student table with id, name, phone and schoolId columns.

The schoolId column is referenced to the id column in school table, but I'd like it to be able to receive null as well

```
REFERENCES School(SchoolID) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

**the logic:** if a student was referred to me from a specific school then i want a reference to the school table but if he is a private student then i want him to have a null in the schoolId column.

what I'm looking to achieve is have a model in Django that is managed and a view that receive request with students data and saves them

my model.py is:

```
class school(models.Model): 
    id= models.AutoField(primary_key=True) 
    name= models.CharField(max_length=150) 
    phonenumber= models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    class Meta:
           managed = True
           db_table = 'school'
class student(models.Model): 
    id= models.AutoField(primary_key=True) 
    name= models.CharField(max_length=150) 
    phonenumber= models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    schoolId = models.ForeignKey(school, db_column='id')
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'student'
```

my view.py looks like this

```
def savestudent(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        student_name=request.POST['name']
        student_phone=request.POST['phone']
        new_student = student(name=student_name,phonenumber=student_phone)
        new_student.save()
```

I'm getting an error: `DoesNotExist: students has no school.`

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

```
create table students (
  id int primary key,
  name text not null,
  phone text not null,
  school_id int references schools(school_id)
);
```

NULL is the default for columns in SQL, so you don't really need to do anything.

You don't need to use DEFERRED or DEFERRABLE.

You should use snake_case identifiers in PostgreSQL.

Comment: If I declare a table like you suggested then when I'm trying from Django saving an instance of student by setting only it's name and phone `s=students(name='Neil', phone='911')` i get an error: `DoesNotExist: students has no school.`